# Android Manifest activity doesn't recognize classes

Tags: java, android

The names of the classes don't show up in green, hovering the mouse over them shows "class or interface expected". The app doesn't get installed when I click run and shows

```
Error while executing: am start -n 
"com.example.alber.piwas/com.example.alber.piwas.Login" -a 
android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=
[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.alber.piwas/.Login }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class 
{com.example.alber.piwas/com.example.alber.piwas.Login} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

This is the code in my AndroidManifest fine. Login, User, and Signup3 are all classes.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.alber.piwas">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.example.alber.piwas.Login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".User">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.alber.piwas.User" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

    <activity android:name=".Signup3">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.alber.piwas.Signup3" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you confirm that `Login` extends `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity` ?

Comment: Yeah   public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

Comment: Did your Login class compiled sucessfully? And is located exactly in the package space + class name you provided?

Comment: I just tried it using an Emulator and it doesn't give that error, but it still does when I use my phone.